# cmake: symbol lookup error: cmake: undefined symbol: uv_translate_sys_error

Tags: c++, cmake

I did some uknown changes to my system after which I am not able to use cmake any more.
A command like this `cmake --version` would emit an error `cmake: symbol lookup error: cmake: undefined symbol: uv_translate_sys_error`.
Please suggest what could be done about this

Comment: The symbol `uv_translate_sys_error` should be defined by libuv library. Check that your libuv library defines that symbol. If you have several installations of libuv library, then check that the symbol is defined by all of these installations (https://github.com/mono/mono/issues/19276)

Comment: @Tsyvarev I updated/installed few pakcage, which installed a corrupted cmake in my stsme. I removed that corrupted cmake and now its working fine. I hvae posted an answer with detail step I followed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out.
It was due to corrupted cmake being installed in the process. This corrupted cmake was present on my path.

1. Find path to all `cmake` avaible on your system usig `whereis cmake` command.
2. Run `/path/to/to/cmake --version` command on each one of them. The corrupt one will throw errors, the working will work all fine.
3. Delete the corrupted one using `sudo rm /path/to/corrupt/cmake`.

This solved my issue. if you only have one cmake and its corrupted than delete it and reinstall it.